# Haskell: "ambiguous type variable arising from using a function", where said variable actually doesn't matter

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following function:

```hs
foo :: Show a => Maybe a -> [Char] 
foo (Just x) = show x 
foo Nothing = "Nothing"
```

Then I try to use this function:

```hs
bar :: [Char]
bar = foo Nothing
```

The argument that has been passed to `foo` is of type `Maybe a` where `a` is not specified, and indeed we don't care about `a`, because we use only the case of `foo` for the `Nothing`. But the GHC claims to provide the concrete type:

> Ambiguous type variable `a0` arising from a use of `foo`
>   prevents the constraint `(Show a0)` from being solved.    Probable
>   fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0` should be.

GHC hints to specify the type. So the only fix I see there is to create a fake type which has an instance of `Show` type class:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, KindSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-methods #-}

data Dummy :: *

instance Show Dummy

bar :: [Char]
bar = foo (Nothing :: Maybe Dummy)

foo :: Show a => Maybe a -> [Char]
foo (Just x) = show x
foo Nothing = "Nothing"
```

It works, but seems to be pretty straightforward. But the real reason why I don't like this solution is because for my purposes this code is automatically generated from some meta data, which doesn't provide information about which particular polymorph type must be specified as `Dummy` (there are may be user data types with more than one parameters). So I wonder, is there any way to tell GHC, that if the type is not specified, this type doesn't matter?

Comment: If the type doesn't matter, then how can it be necessary to “providce information about which particular polymorphic type must be specified”? If it _really_ doesn't matter, then `foo (Nothing :: Maybe ())` should be ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"doesn't matter" is a property of the instance, and ghc doesn't introspect instances like that. For some types, it does matter. The `Show` instance for `[a]` depends on the type `a`, even when the list is empty. Check out the result of `show ([] :: [Char])` vs the result of `show ([] :: [Int])`.

But all of that is sort of an aside. The fact is, types are determined at compile time, but values are determined at run time. You have presented a situation for which the type variables don't matter for only some input values. In this case, the type variables still matter, because they control behavior in the other cases.

You're going to have to properly resolve the ambiguous types, because that's how ghc knows which code to use. There are some techniques for doing it conveniently, like using the ScopedTypeVariables extension, but it's hard to recommend one without having a more representative piece of code. The most important thing I can say is that it really does matter, though, because instance selection is done at compile time, long before a value is ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

The type checker doesn't know what `foo` does with its argument, and specifically doesn't know that `Nothing` won't actually be used. But it *does* know that the argument must have type `Show a => Maybe a`, and `Nothing` has the more general type `Maybe a`. It's up to you to provide a sufficiently narrowly typed argument when calling `foo`.

There's no need to define a new dummy type; any existing type with a `Show` instance will do.

```
bar :: [Char]
bar = foo (Nothing :: Maybe ())
```